# Respond with an error if dates and names overlap with each other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I think my brain is going to explode. I must be thinking about this to much.

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to keep track of apartments and cars for a construction project. We only have so many cars and so many apartments. Im trying to schedule subcontractors so they don't overlap with each others apartments and cars.

Here is the code I have so far...

`=IF(ARRAYFORMULA(B:B)=Data!$A$1,IF(DATEVALUE(D17)>=DATEVALUE(D18),IF(DATEVALUE(E18)>=DATEVALUE(E17),"Ok","Overlap")"Ok","Overlap"),"")`

Please see my spreadsheet here for a better example of what I am looking for.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17t_8nhKfu3vy3OpAWZ_6Ep5Xn-4kwo8Xo4E6WuYVbFY/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the formula below and paste it on the `H3` cell for example. Afterwards, you will have to drag it down the column such that all the entries are covered.

As for the formula, it makes use of `IF` and `COUNTIFS` in order to check the conditions:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B$3:B3,B3,D$3:D3,"<="&D3,E$3:E3,">="&D3)>1,"Date Overlap",IF(COUNTIFS(C$3:C3,C3,D$3:D3,"<="&D3,E$3:E3,">="&D3)>1,"Vehicle Overlap","Ok"))
```

#### Reference

- [COUNTIFS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550);
- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364).

Comment: You are an amazing human! Thank you for your help!